# .NET list sort returns different order after all returns of 0

Tags: c#, .net, list, sorting

The initial list that goes in on this, comes out a different order, even when return of 0 is applied.  I thought a return of 0 keeps the games in the same order as it was being processed initially but this doesnt seem to be the case.  If none of the other returns are hit, shouldnt the order stay the same as the origional array?

```
games.Sort((game1, game2) =>
            {
                DateTime? minMaxDate1 = null;
                DateTime? minMaxDate2 = null;

                minMaxDate1 = FindDateRestriction(autoSchedulerLists, game1.AwayTeam, minMaxDate1);
                minMaxDate1 = FindDateRestriction(autoSchedulerLists, game1.HomeTeam, minMaxDate1);

                minMaxDate2 = FindDateRestriction(autoSchedulerLists, game2.AwayTeam, minMaxDate2);
                minMaxDate2 = FindDateRestriction(autoSchedulerLists, game2.HomeTeam, minMaxDate2);

                if (minMaxDate1.HasValue && !minMaxDate2.HasValue)
                    return -1;

                if (minMaxDate2.HasValue && !minMaxDate1.HasValue)
                    return -1;

                if (minMaxDate1.HasValue && minMaxDate2.HasValue && minMaxDate1 != minMaxDate2)
                {
                    return minMaxDate1 < minMaxDate2 ? -1 : 1;
                }

                return 0;
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> shouldnt the order stay the same as the origional array if all items return 0?

No, [`List<T>.Sort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z(v=vs.110).aspx) ...

> performs an **unstable** sort; that is, if two elements are equal, their
>   order might not be preserved. In contrast, a stable sort preserves the
>   order of elements that are equal

If you want a stable sort you could use LINQ's [`OrderBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx).

> This method performs a **stable** sort; that is, if the keys of two
>   elements are equal, the order of the elements is preserved. In
>   contrast, an unstable sort does not preserve the order of elements
>   that have the same key.

So something like:

```
games = games.OrderBy(g => /* logic here */)
             .ToList();
```

Comment: I used the IComparer overload on the OrderBy and it worked.